# (Python) zlib.compressObj.compress doesn't give me the original argument of zlib.decompress

Tags: python, json, compression, zlib

So I've been given this JSON in compressed form, which I can decompress into a byte string with `zlib.decompress(compressed, wbits=-15)` (I noticed it works for any wbits from -15 to -8), and I have to make some changes to it and re-compress it in the same format.

I've tried using

```
comp_obj = zlib.compressobj(level, zlib.DEFLATED, wbits)
comp = comp_obj.compress(decompressed)
comp += comp_obj.flush()
```

where `level` was every value in `range(1, 10)` and `wbits` every value in `range(-15, -8)`, and none of them give me the original compressed string. They give me something that I can then decompress successfully, but I need it to be exactly the same.

Why does this not work? How do I get the original compressed string?

Comment: The problem is your "need" for it to be exactly the same. All that matters is that it decompress to the original uncompressed data, which it will.

Comment: What do you mean "make some changes to it"? If you change it, of course the result will be different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in control of the compression, then in general you *cannot expect to be able to reproduce the same compressed data* from the uncompressed data. The result can vary due to the use of different compression code, a different version of the same compression code, or different settings of the same version of the same compression code.

The only guarantee is that for *x* -> lossless compression -> decompression -> *y*, then *y* is exactly the same as *x*. There is never a guarantee for *p* -> decompression -> lossless compression -> *q* that *q* is equal to *p*.